# Math and volume of a liquid

Tags: volume

I am trying to calculate the amount of chlorine in water- I have to dilute it because its hyper chlorinated and the testing system only goes up to 10 parts per million (chlorine should be 50ppm and greater). So, I am taking a 10 milliliter sample. I take this 10 ml sample and combine it with 90 milliliters of pure water (non chlorinated) and mix to make 100ml total.

When I test, it is diluted and I just need to know by what do I multiply to get my correct parts per million figure?

Comment: Multiply the test result by 10.

Answer (score 1):

So you've got 10g of water and in it are (let's say your value is spot on) 500μg of chlorine.  This gives your 50ppm.  If you add another 90g of water, now you've got 100g of water, and 500μg of chlorine in it still.  Do that division and you'd get 5ppm.  Which is 1/10 of what you had originally, so to get back to 50, you multiply by 10.